# Strange Xcode warning pops up above imports

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

I've been struggling to fix this warning, however,it didn't disappear regardless of hundreds times of deleting and retyping.I guess it's Xcode 6 bug that appears on certain machines, or something else. I wonder if any of you guys have encountered this stupid warning at all?![unnecessary fixable red warning ][1]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6om8y3y9belb4b/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-08%20at%205.09.24%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Post the code for that whole file (including any commented out stuff at the top) so we can see everything you  have in there.

Comment: have you checked prefix.pch? also try to delete derived data and clean to index again

Comment: I've not checket prefix. What should I be looking for in prefix.pch?

Comment: ohh geez, I can't find prefix file :/ .

Comment: There is no automatically created prefix.ch in Xcode 6, so that's not your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check all #import statements, possibly an infinite loop is a cause of this!

protip:
Use **@class SomeButton**; in .h-file where it can, and actually **#import SomeButton.h** in the .m-file.